# add a check to validate the field doesn't receive some type of char

Tags: java, mysql, validation, jsp

i'm programing a java web application where some fields in jsp require specific characters (remove diacritics).This task is not hard with javascript and a verification method in the servlet side but still possible add the characters if somebody (coworker maybe) forget about the validations.

so i don't know if is possible add the validation in a area where nobody gonna modify so often like the database.

Comment: Could you write your question as something like 'I want to add something to the database to automagically remove x chars when updating/inserting a row' or 'I want to add a check to validate the field doesn't receive some type of char...'? :)

Comment: ok. i will use "I want to add a check to validate the field doesn't receive some type of char"

Comment: Seems then, that a constrait check would suffice. You add a check that says "a record must obey this rule" and the rule can be "this char is not found in string and this other char... and...". You can use `instr` for that. Or define a special function to use (but I don't know that much). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you might be able to create a trigger to watch for this

Comment: thank for the answer.
i've not used trigger before, but after search in google i saw some examples. maybe i need start to study about stored procedure.
i'm gonna left the question open for a while to see if somebody have another point of view.

Comment: i'm sorry for the late answer about the solution.

The solution was the use of comparison operator and `locate(substr,str)` to find any character.

Example:

`BEGIN
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(100);
set msg=concat('Error');
IF LOCATE('ñ',NEW.Name) > 0 THEN
  signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
END IF;
END
`

the only problem with this is the character codification. if you not use UTF-8 spanish, character like ñ are detected as n.